# Given Server Relative URL, quickest way to find the last thing (i.e. after final slash)

Tags: string, url, split, match, relative-path

I'm assuming:

```
String abc = "My Documents/FileName.txt".Split('/')[1]; // is not the quickest way
```

Is it?

Comment: It helps if you're explicit about the language you're working with. I'm assuming you're referring to Javascript given your example.

Answer (score 2):

```
String abc = "My Documents/FileName.txt";
abc = abc.Substring(abc.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

This has the following virtues:

1. there is no slash, in which case it just returns the name, and
2. there are multiple slashes, in which case it returns just the final component
3. it creates the fewest number of intermediate objects